# Unexpected char 0x0a in header value when using OkHttp client in Android

Tags: java, android, base64, retrofit, okhttp

When sending a Base64 encoded string as header using Http, I am getting error response as

`Unexpected char 0x0a at 28 in header value: I99Uy+HjG5PpEhmi8vZgm0W7KDQ=`

Usage :

`String encodedHeader = Base64.encodeToString(value.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
header.put("auth", encodedHeader);`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`0x0a` is a newline character which is forbidden in a header.
Solution would be to make sure that these characters are stripped off before sending the encoded value as header.

`Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);`
this avoids wrapping with a platform specific newline character(s).

Comment: If you use Okio’s ByteString, base64 is easier: `encodedHeader = ByteString.encodeUtf8(value).base64();`

Comment: @priyankvex thanks for the solution. It works like charm. But I didn't understand " this avoids wrapping with a platform specific newline character". Can you please make me understand this. Thanks :)