# setRequestProperty exception using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am having an issue when setting the Authorization header using `setRequestProperty`. It appears that the total length of the property value cannot exceed 80 bytes.

```
        if(headerData != null) {
            for (Pair pair : headerData) {
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty(pair.first.toString(),pair.second.toString());
            }
        }
```

The pair is:

"Authorization", "Basic TW9oYW5ATmV0UmVhY2gtTW9oYW5zLUFQR3JvdXA6TW9oYW5ATmV0UmVhY2gtTW9oYW5zLUFQR3Jv
dXA=\n"

The error is:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x0a at 82 in header value**

If I reduce the total length of the value to be under 80, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Unexpected char 0x0a in header value when using OkHttp client in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026163/unexpected-char-0x0a-in-header-value-when-using-okhttp-client-in-android)

I just needed to set the base64 encoding option to `Base64.NO_WRAP`